# Global Object Vs Singelton pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Can global object (in C++) always replace Singleton pattern ? If yes, whats the advantage of Singleton pattern ?

Comment: Warning: sweeping generalisation ahead! You're probably better off using neither.

Answer (score 2):

Both provide different functionality,

A global object creates an object at global scope which can be accessed across multiple translation units while singleton pattern restricts the users to be able to create a single object for that particular class.

Bottomline:
You are comparing apples and oranges. You chose one depending the functionality you want to achieve.

Comment: Are they really *that* different? Almost all of the time, singleton seems to be used as moral equivalent of a global because "globals are evil, duh". A singleton object, unless explicitly restricted to the current TU via `static`/`namespace {}` (which I've *never* seen done) can be accessed across multiple TUs as well. A global object also exists only once. Although you *can* create other instances of its type, in practice it is rarely done.

Comment: @delnan: Absolutely, the singleton pattern applies to a class. It's about restricting the ability to create multiple instances of a class. A global object can be created of any type without the need to modify that type (if of class type); the type doesn't need any knowledge of whether it is being used as a global or not. With most globals, there is no harm by having other instances of the type in use in a program.

Answer (score 0):

A global object is available across your program (this makes it seem easier to manage for a beginner, until you start do do anything non-trivial, which then becomes a nightmare to debug because it could be *any* of the code causing the error). It is strongly frowned upon.

A singleton is an object which has a limitation that you can only make one of them. They feel global because they are accessed in a global way through a static function usually, and so it still could be *any* of your code corrupting the object when debugging, so it is just as much a pain to manage. Depending on the language and clique/community/book, it is strongly frowned upon.

Your question seems to be asking for the "right" way in some sense. The best way is to avoid them altogether and encapulate your data nicely in classes, and pass them clearly as arguments to functions.

Answer (score 0):

One advantage I see that one doesn't have control on creation of global object and at times could be costly when object needs scarce resources but by lazy creation in singleton method, you can defer creation of object until it is first accessed.